# Pandas- Groupby multiple columns and mean from a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe of the following structure which is simplified for the purpose of this question:

```
  A     B     C D ... J K 
  date1 time1 1 1 ... 1 1
  date2 time2 2 2 ... 2 2
```

Essentially the first 3 columns all represent string data i.e times and dates. The dataframe I am reading in from a csv file and the data after the times has multiple points on a single day for each column.

What I wish to do is find a way to group all the data by dates and create mean values per day which account for multiple datapoints on a single day. This is handled nicely by using group.by(dates) however I lose all of the other data not included in the dates column so the result is like so:

Before group.by().mean():

```
   A     B     C D ... J K
   date1 time1 1 1 ... 1 1
   date2 time2 2 2 ... 2 2
   date2 time3 1 1 ... 1 1
```

After:

```
   A      C   D   ... J   K
   date1  1   1       1   1
   date2  1.5 1.5 ... 1.5 1.5
```

My ideal output would be to keep the data in the time column and date column whilst still creating mean values based on the days. This would result in the following:

Ideal output:

```
   A      B     C   D   ... J   K
   date1  time1 1   1       1   1
   date2  time2 1.5 1.5 ... 1.5 1.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem you need aggregate columns with `strings` and `times` too, e.g. by [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), else are [omited](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns).

So possible solution is create `dict of aggregation functions` and use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
print (df)

   A      B      C  D  E  J  K
0  a  date1  time1  1  1  1  1
1  b  date2  time2  2  2  2  2
2  c  date2  time3  1  1  1  1

cols = ['A','B','C']
d = {x:'mean' for x in df.columns.difference(cols)}
d['A'] = 'first'
d['C'] = 'first'
print (d)
{'E': 'mean', 'D': 'mean', 'J': 'mean', 'A': 'first', 'C': 'first', 'K': 'mean'}

df1 = df.groupby('B').agg(d).reset_index().reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df1)
   A      B      C    D    E    J    K
0  a  date1  time1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  b  date2  time2  1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5
```

Comment: Yep with a little bit of tweaking to fit my program this is what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!